# Update Firebase Timestamp Value

Tags: java, android, firebase, timestamp

I want to update the initial server timestamp value stored in my firebase database, so i did it in such a way that the timestamp value will be updated subsequently, but this seems to be causing major problem when i run the app, at first it works fine but after changing the value twice then it just freezes like the timestamp is constantly updated. I don.t know how i can make it perfect.

Below is the code were i add and want to change the timestamp value.

```
  mRootRef.child("Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(mChatUser)){
                Map chatAddMap = new HashMap();
                chatAddMap.put("seen",false);
                chatAddMap.put("uid",mChatUser);
                chatAddMap.put("timestamp", ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);

                Map chatUserMap = new HashMap();
                chatUserMap.put("Chat/" + mCurrentUserId + "/" + mChatUser,chatAddMap);
                chatUserMap.put("Chat/" + mChatUser + "/" + mCurrentUserId,chatAddMap);

                mRootRef.updateChildren(chatUserMap, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, DatabaseReference databaseReference) {

                        if (databaseError != null){
                            Log.d("CHAT LOG", databaseError.getMessage().toString());
                        }

                    }
                });
            }else {

                mRootRef.child("Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser).child("timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {


        }
    });
```

Comment: updating timestamps would get easy if you do that using cloud function . .

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Is your function connected to cloud function? Have you ever coded Firebase cloud function? I mean just asking to know how much I need to code for you . If you know typescript that's easy.. or let me know how your function works I'll explain it to you with a code example

Comment: @Dharmaraj I don't really know much about typescript but i have done a little cloud function code because that is what i used for my notification service in my app.

Comment: @Dharmaraj Using a cloud function for this would be overkill. This is just a simple infinite loop bug. In this code, the value of `Chat/${mCurrentUserId}/${mChatUser}` is set, which fires the listener, which sets the value of `Chat/${mCurrentUserId}/${mChatUser}`, which fires the listener, etc. The solution could be as simple as swapping out `addValueEventListener` for `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`

Comment: @samthecodingman I had thought his overall function could be ran via cloud functions. Confusion occured when I saw the onDataChange. Sorry for that

Comment: so what do you suggest i do to solve this?

Comment: @Eric Have you tried the swap I mentioned?

Comment: yes I have done that and it did not work

Comment: Would be easier to understand the problem if you post an example of what your data looks like and the condition you want the timestamp to update

Comment: If it is still unstable after changing `addValueEventListener` to `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, it may be because there are more than one instance of this mobile app. All running instances of the app may be reading and then attempting to update. The idea of @Dharmaraj to do it with a simple cloud function should be the best way. Only one entity would then be listening for a change and would do the update. Even then, you need to be careful that the cloud function doesn't get in an infinite loop either. But at least, better than have multiple copies of the app trying to do the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution to my problem and i feel i should post it here because this issue doesn't seem to have any solution online.

So what is happening here is that i did not add a check for a situation that needs to be true before `timestamp` will be updated, there by causing the endless loop since it doesn't know when to stop.

So I resolved it by simply wrapping this code

```
                mRootRef.child("Chat").child(mCurrentUserId).child(mChatUser).child("timestamp").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
```

in an if statement that checks if the new time is equal to the value already stored in firebase, if it is true it dose nothing but if it is not only then it should update to current time.